# R load a method from a package

Tags: r

I've got a large package. I'd like just one method (and any dependencies it has) to be loaded without having to load the whole package. Is this possible?

Comment: By "library" do you mean "package"? If so, what's the package?  What's the method?  It may or may not be masked.

Comment: If the function that uses the method is not masked, it can be found quickly with `showMethods(package::function)` provided it's an S4 generic.

Comment: I hope the OP meant "package" because otherwise my edits are nonsense.  They can roll back (and explain what they mean) if I'm wrong.

Comment: @BenBolker I have a feeling "method" may be replaced with "function" as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call upon the specific function in R with the following operator and form: `(package name)::(function)`. An example would be calling upon the `round_any()` function in the package `plyr` such as

```
> plyr::round_any(134, accuracy = 10)
[1] 130
```

Comment: If this doesn't satisfy your question, I will remove the incorrect answer.

Comment: Also ::: is sometimes helpful for calling non-exported functions.